# custom GUI TextField's and ObjectField's don't assign values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

**I am having problems mutating referenced values** through using Unity's API for modifying the Editor GUI.

When I go into the editor to change the values in the GUI, it just refreshes and retains the label text/object I provide in the arguments, why isn't it mutating the reference and displaying that instead?

**1.**
I am referencing a class attached to a particular Game-object `ButtonManager script = target as ButtonManager;`

I want to change the values of that class `script.thisImageCaption = EditorGUILayout.TextArea("Content for the main image slide", script.thisImageCaption);` but this does not work

odly though... **bools work, when I check the box, the GUI remembers my choice and modifys the referenced value, so why don't the others?**
 `script.hasAudioClip = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Voice Over?", script.hasAudioClip);`

**2.**
I am also referencing GameObjects and their Individual Components

```
//following code is a snippet of code, the full context isnt provided, only the context related to mutating referenced values

List<Tuple<int, Text, Image>> imageCloneHolder = new List<Tuple<int, Text, Image>>();

imageCloneHolder.Add(new Tuple<int, Text, Image>(
slide.GetInstanceID(),
slide.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>(),//get reference to text
slide.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>()//get reference to image
));

item.Item2.text = EditorGUILayout.TextArea("Content for the image cloneslide", 
item.Item2.text);//dosen't modify the referenced text 

item.Item3.sprite = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("This second Image slides image", 
item.Item3.sprite, 
typeof(Sprite), 
false) as Sprite;//doesn't modify the referenced image
```

I don't quite understand what's wrong, I thought when you grabbed references in Unity & C#(with classes,components, etc) they would be pointers to the real object not a copy, but it appears Unity's API for the GUI is having me modify copies? Is this not true for strings referenced in a class? Or for some Unity Components?

**Screen Dump**

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WVKS.jpg

Editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ0LD.jpg

Comment: You should **not** directly modify values of the `target` but rather go through [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) this looks a bit more complex but your main issue is that currently you don't mark stuff as *dirty* so changes are never saved. Using the `SerializedProperty` Unity handles all of that marking dirty and redo/undo automatically. I would need more code especially the full Editor and at least the class with all fields to help you implement it.

Comment: @derHugo I've shared a screen dump in the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I guess is that you don't mark stuff as *dirty*. This is required to save any changes.

In general you should **not** directly make changes to the `target` from within an `Editor`. Rather use [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html). They handle all the marking stuff *dirty* (thus saving changes) and Undo/Redo functionality for you.

Also I don't see why you are using a `List` there if anyway you are adding only one element...

I don't see your full code especially the class and full Editor would be helpful. But for what you provided it should be something like

```
public class YourEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty thisImageCaption;
    private SerializedProperty hasAudioClip;

    // wherever you get this from
    private XY item;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Link SerializedProperties to the real ones
        thisImageCaption = serializedObject.FindProperty("thisImageCaption");
        hasAudioClip = serializedObject.FindProperty("hasAudioClip");
    }

    public override void OnInpectorGUI()
    {
        // Load the current real values
        // into the SerializedProperties
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Now only change the SerializedProperties
        thisImageCaption.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextArea("Content for the main image slide", thisImageCaption.stringValue);

        // Using PropertyField automatically
        // uses the property drawer according
        // to the property's type
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(hasAudioClip);

        // now to the tricky part
        // for both slider sub-components you will need
        // to create a serializedObject from the given components e.g.
        var textSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(item.Item2);
        var imageSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(item.Item3);

        // do the update for both
        textSerializedObject.Update();
        imageSerializedObject.Update();

        // now change what you want to change via serializedProperties e.g.
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(textSerializedObject.FindProperty("m_text"), new GUIContent("Content for the image cloneslide"));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(imageSerializedObject.FindProperty("m_Sprite"), new GUIContent("This second Image slides image"));

        // Write changes back to the real components
        textSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        imageSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: How does Unity know what serializedObject we are finding properties on? That's where I am really confused. What happens when multiple objects have the sane property names on them? How would Unity be able to discern any differences?

Comment: is it from the [CustomEditor(typeof(ButtonManager))] attribute that it knows which serializeObject?

Comment: Everytime you focus e.g. a new GameObject Unity creates Editor instances for each of it's components. Those Editor instances automatically are linked to their according serializedObject of the component they are the inspector for. E.g. all of your GameObjects have the `Transform` component with the same properties but different values. But the Inspector is always linked to the according instances. Especially when it comes to multiple objects selected it gets interesting ;)

Comment: The [CustomEditor] attribute is more or less only relevant so Unity knows that for the type `ButtonManager` there exists a custom editor and it shouldn't use the default one. Besides that it takes some parameters to adjust certain Editor behaviours further.